# The acpi error occurred on Linux boot

Tags: linux

```
[    0.133440] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.133440] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.133440] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.133440] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
[    0.133440] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] reserved in E820
[    0.133440] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.137025] HugeTLB registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.137025] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.137063] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.137064] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.137065] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.137065] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.138810] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.138810] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.138810] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP04.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    0.138926] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP09.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.138930] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.138933] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP08.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto this answer since I had the same happen with Linux Mint 20 recently, and none of the answers posted everywhere else were necessary in my case:

I ran the `exit` command, which suggested using the command [fsck](https://linuxhandbook.com/fsck-command/) for one of my disk partitions. After I did that, the partition got fixed and my system was able to boot successfully after a restart.

Hope it helps someone in case they come across this same issue.

Comment: To be clear: Just type `fsck`, a space, and the full path to the volume it was complaining about, starting with a slash. I guess my laptop ran out of juice before it could suspend myself, at exactly the wrong moment. I should stop using the crappy old battery.

Answer (score 0):

How did you encounter this problem ?
I faced with ACPI error when installing ubuntu 18.04 on MSI laptop.

**To fix acpi error** please try the following step:

1) update your BIOS:

- Update your BOIS to the latest version

2) BIOS setting:

- fast boot = Disable
- secure boot = Disable
- Boot mode select =UEFI

3)Reboot system

- Go to the Install Ubuntu option (BUT DONT PRESS ENTER)
- Press e
- Find the line that starts with linux then add modprobe.blacklist=nouveau after quiet splash.

https://medium.com/@loopsworx/computer-freeze-when-installing-ubuntu-18-04-acpi-error-de18ef8cdfb1?source=friends_link&sk=2d8d3b0315488e1bfc8eb7cbfee1cddc

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error with Linux Mint 19, my OS worked fine and suddenly Linux booted right into emergency mode with your error.

[This thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2401729) led me to checking my /etc/fstab which I had previously edited to add an external hard drive. After removing my own edits there it booted normally.

Looking for a solution now to add my external hard drive without causing that error.